# Change Windows 10 Power Slider programmatically

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, batch, power-management

I want to set the Windows 10 power slider programmatically using poweshell or another CLI tool. I tried with the `powecfg` commande but it doesn't seem to affect the position of the slider. 
I tried using the two modes

```
powercfg /setactive 381B4222-F694-41F0-9685-FF5BB260DF2E  #Better performance


powercfg /setactive DED574B5-45A0-4F42-8737-46345C09C238  #Best Performance
```

However, the slider doesn't change

Comment: You are closing the Power Configuration window between each command?

Comment: yes, you can try it. it doesn't move.

Comment: Your cmds do not affect the power plan

Comment: @somebadhat "If I remember correctly powercfg /setactive requires a restart to take effect."  I use this all the time.  It does not require a restart.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here for information on how to adjust the power mode / power slider programmatically using C#.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68318696/4647297

I created a command-line program which can be used to set the power mode, and it can be found at https://github.com/AaronKelley/PowerMode.

Answer (score -1):

The TechNet article on [customizing the power slider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/customize-power-slider) should answer your questions - I'll add points here:

- There are 4 default "modes" the slider can be in, which change the slider's settings
- The battery slider does not actually change which Power Plan you are in:

> Each slider mode should be thought of as a "lite" power plan, which
>   only contains settings that impact performance, such as CPU settings
>   (PPM) and power throttling. Other factors which control performance
>   (GPU, thermals etc) are in OEM/SVs control and they can create custom
>   power-settings for those and connect them to the slider via the INF

- There are no handy commands/tools/APIs for selecting which power slider location you want to be at.
- You can customize the slider values yourself to different performance values.

All that being said, if you are particularly knowledgeable, you may be able to extract the correct classes out of `C:\Windows\System32\SettingsHandlers_OneCore_BatterySaver.dll`, which does the lifting behind making changes and updating the various UI elements.

Comment: There doesn't need to be a space between "/setactive" and the power plan GUID. No need to restart either. However, you should use "powercfg.exe /setactive", not just "powercfg".

Comment: I read that article already, but it just provides information about making customization. I am sure that messing with the classes will do the trick but it will be hard to do.